# Flutter Chewie next and back button

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-android, flutter-video-player

I want to put these buttons for android in Flutter chewie package, how can I do it.[image]

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation:

```
additionalOptions: (context) {
  return <OptionItem>[
    OptionItem(
      onTap: () => debugPrint('My option works!'),
      iconData: Icons.chat,
      title: 'My localized title',
    ),
    OptionItem(
      onTap: () =>
          debugPrint('Another option working!'),
      iconData: Icons.chat,
      title: 'Another localized title',
    ),
  ];
},
```

Use `TextButton` or any other tappable widget and create the needed options.